# remove whitespace in fetchxml?

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I have a problem with searching strings. Phonenumber is a string. And sometimes written as "111 11 111" and other times "11111111". Are there any attributes to remove whitespaces when searching?
So that if a user writes "11111111" the fetchxml will find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this in the query itself.
I would suggest creating a new attribute to hold "cleaned" phone number, populated by workflow or a plugin on save of the record.
Then include this new field in quick find search fields and use that one in the FetchXML query.